# Where do I download HBOOT 2.16?

Tags: device-firmware, htc-one-s

I need HBOOT 2.16 to flash my preferred ROM on a HTC One S.

I can't figure out where to download the firmware itself. The only page I've found which even vaguely resembles clear instructions is [this one](https://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-one-s/general/guide-how-to-install-hboot-2-16-time-t2898605) but the [download link](https://mega.co.nz/#!EAJFFDAK!KczIBV2jCY71Vf_AOM1UVDA6Z_4EwGxyqyq05XzjrnQ) for the firmware is broken. The other pages I've seen present a very muddled picture and no links through which to download the actual firmware.

I have a rooted device, S-OFF, super CID 11111111, formerly H3G__001 I believe.

I'm going round in circles trying to figure this out. How do I upgrade my firmware?

Comment: Situation seems bad. Do you have the S3 or S4 variant? [AndroidRUU](http://www.androidruu.com/index.php?developer=Ville) lists the latest 3.16.x firmwares which contain HBOOT 2.15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an S4 variant.

Check [this XDA-Developers thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2751518) out - latest official (but unofficially obtained) firmware at version 4.05.401.1, with HBOOT 2.16. Link is hosted on AFH and is pretty good in quality.